# mysql replication (TokuDB replica): Column X of table 'database.table' cannot be converted from type 'varchar(Y)' to type 'varchar(Y)'

Tags: mysql, innodb, tokudb

Experienced this error when reviewing the output of

```
SHOW SLAVE STATUS\;
```

this is the excerpt from the status output:

```
   Last_SQL_Errno: 1677
   Last_SQL_Error: Column 1 of table 'database.table' cannot be converted 
                   from type 'varchar(16)' to type 'varchar(16)'
```

### Configuration:

Master - Mysql 5.6.x // table with error has ENGINE=InnoDB

Replica - Percona 5.6.x // table with error has ENGINE=TokuDB

The column definitions on the master and the replicate servers match exactly:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE database.table;

....
    CREATE TABLE `table` (
      `column_0` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `column_1` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
      `column_2` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that there *was* one difference between the definition of the two tables.

The CHARSET was the the true culprit.

Master:

```
...
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=XXXXX DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Replica:

```
...
) ENGINE=TokuDB AUTO_INCREMENT=XXXX DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Command required to "fix" the table before restarting the replication:

```
ALTER TABLE database.table CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET latin1;
```