# Apply Error 1677: Column 59 of table `sales_orders` cannot be converted from type `datetime` to type `varchar(10)`

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

When I execute following query on **Amazon RDS read replica** it gives me an error

`Apply Error 1677: Column 59 of table sales_orders cannot be converted from type datetime to type varchar(10)`

Query I'm executing on Read Replica

```
ALTER TABLE `sales_orders` 
ADD COLUMN `dw_base_currency` VARCHAR(10) NULL AFTER `source`,
ADD COLUMN `dw_base_total` DECIMAL(12,4) NULL AFTER `dw_base_currency`;
```

I've checked character set of table described in answer at [mysql replication (TokuDB replica): Column X of table 'database.table' cannot be converted from type 'varchar(Y)' to type 'varchar(Y)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28117231/mysql-replication-tokudb-replica-column-x-of-table-database-table-cannot-be) but in my case character set of table is same.

Comment: Why are you altering a table on a replica?

Comment: I want to prepare few reports so adding column to read replica those columns doesn't make sense in `master`.

Answer (score 3):

When the changes caused by a query are replicated, if the master chooses to log the event in `ROW` format, the column names are not written to the log -- only the values, ordered by the ordinal position of each column in the table definition.

This means the replica can have either more or fewer columns than the master, but if that is true, the discrepancy must be restricted to the rightmost columns on the table.

Your changes to the replica apparently introduced new columns somewhere in the middle, and this isn't valid.

> You can replicate a table from the master to the slave such that the master and slave copies of the table have differing numbers of columns, subject to the following conditions:
>
> - Columns common to both versions of the table must be defined in the same order on the master and the slave.
>
> (This is true even if both tables have the same number of columns.)
>
> - Columns common to both versions of the table must be defined before any additional columns.
>
> This means that executing an `ALTER TABLE` statement on the slave where a new column is inserted into the table within the range of columns common to both tables causes replication to fail [...]
>
> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-replication-excerpt/5.7/en/replication-features-more-columns.html